# Make a line animation that is thicker at the start and thinner at the end?

Tags: animation

At 00:40 to 00:42 of the following YouTube video, a line that is thicker at the start and thinner at the end is moving along a path, as if you move a fireball. This is a Blender tutorial channel, so this is probably made with Blender, but there is no tutorial for that part. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxpjudV_88&t=40

[image]
[image]

How can I make it like a thinning line like the video above?

PS: This is the animation I made after learning from the accepted answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/paLDr.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with **curve only** or with **mesh and *Curve* modifier**:

**- With curves only:**

Create your line curve, create a second curve that will be your taper, make it flat with <kbd>V</kbd> > *Vector*, rotate it slightly on the Z axis in *Edit* mode, the rotation angle will give the thickness of your line, i.e. the difference between its minimum and maximum radius. Now choose this second curve as the *Taper Object* of your line:

[image]

If you enable the *Map Taper* option and play with *Bevel Start* and *End* values you'll be able to animate your line:

[image]

You need to play with both the *Start* and *End* values if you want the line to follow along the curve:

[image]

Settings at frame 0:

[image]

Settings at frame 20:

[image]

The file: [image]

**- With mesh and *Curve* modifier:**

Put the cylinder at the same point as the curve's origin, and make sure that the curve's direction is good, if not, go in *Edit* mode and right click > *Switch Direction*:

[image]

Give your object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*, then animate the cylinder along the X axis so that the mesh follows the curve.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but there is one big problem. Using the bevel method, the line is just growing like this https://imgur.com/iwES1A0 , not moving like the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saxpjudV_88&t=40 . Also, pressing `v` had no effect on my Blender. It would be helpful if you explain how to adjust the "taping" (thin/thickness control) in more details (how to make thicker/thinner).

Comment: Animating both Bevel Start/End does not give me the move effect I need, because the moving line's end did not get any thinner.

Comment: I've edited my answer, does it answer?

Comment: Yeah, after inspecting your example file and some trial-and-error, I could achieve the same effect in a new Blender file.